# How to properly terminate strings in C programming?

Tags: c

I'm using scanf to scan 5 product names and store them in a string. However, when i print them, the last one is always printed as ♣. Where am i going wrong ?

I am trying to take in the id, name and prices of 5 products and print them using structures. However the last product name is always printed as ♣. I realised that this may be due to improper terminating of the string, and tried the solutions provided to such questions.
I saw another similar question on strings and tried to terminate the string properly by doing, char name[50]={'0'};    in my code. This part is within the structure part of the code.

```
struct product
 {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    int price;
 };

void main()
 {
    struct product p [5];
    int i,a;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the id no., name and price of the product %d\n",i);
        scanf("%d%s%d",&p[i].id,&p[i].name,&p[i].price);
    }
    printf("The id no., name and price of the product %d are\n",i);
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d\t%s/0\t%d\n",p[i].id,p[i].name,p[i].price);
    }
}
```

The final output, that is p[5].name ,should've been what i had entered, but is, however, ♣.
And if i try to terminate the code by entering: char name[50]={'\0'};
it puts up an error message over the '=' saying that it expected a ';'.

Comment: Don't forget that all array indexes in C are zero-based. That is, an array of say `5` elements have indexes from `0` to `4` (inclusive).

Comment: regarding; `void main()`  Regardless of what some compilers (for instance visual studio) allow, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!  amongst other things, it is missing necessary `#include` statements for the needed header files.  are you expecting us to guess as to which header files you actually included?

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d%s%d",&p[i].id,&p[i].name,&p[i].price);`  In C, a reference to an array name (like 'name[]' ) degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  So this parameter: `&p[i].name` is asking for the address of an address which is not what you want.  Suggest: `p[i].name`.  Notice no `'&'.  Your compiler should have told you about this

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d%s%d",&p[i].id,&p[i].name,&p[i].price);`  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values).  any other value than the number of 'input format specifiers' indicates an error

Comment: Off topic: If you're going to terminate a string '0' is the ascii coding for a printable zero character. The number 0 without quotes is a binary value equal to zero. Strings are terminated with the binary zero. It's not "printable" so it was chosen as an end marker. It just happens to be displayed as a club on your system.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. Always.

Comment: @user3629249 While you are right in theory, this particular case is a nobrainer. It's pretty obvious that you only need to add `#include <stdio.h>` and then it compiles just fine.

Comment: @klutt,  That may be so, but it is NOT our job to 'fill in the blanks' on the OPs code.  The OP ask why there is a run time problem with their code.  Therefore, they need to post code that can run, as is.

Comment: @user3629249 It was my mistake. While making notes for myself i usually exclude the header file as it is always <stdio.h>  and <conio.h>. Hence, i forgot to include it here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with termination of strings. [Note 1]

Your problem is that arrays in C start at index 0, not index 1. So the elements in `p` are `p[0]` through `p[4]` and so `p[5]` references random memory. C does not check that array indexes are valid, and using invalid ones leads to odd bugs like this one.

`scanf` certainly NUL-terminates strings, which is why I said that termination is not a problem. However, it doesn't know how much memory you've reserved for the string, so it could well overwrite random memory if the string entered by the user is too long. Better to use the format `"%d%49s%d"` (in this case) to limit the string read to 49 characters. (You can't fit a 50-character string in a 50-element array precisely because you need to leave space for the terminating NUL.)

However, you also need to check the return value of `scanf`. That function returns the number of successful conversions, which in this case must be three. If it returns a smaller number, that means one of the conversions failed, and if a numeric conversion fails, the offending character (perhaps a letter) will still be the next input character, so the next `%d` conversion will also fail.

---

#### Notes:

1. If you want to store a NUL in a string, you would do something like;this, assuming you know where the string ends:

   ```
    p[i].name[len] = `\0`;
   ```

   You can declare and initialise a character array so that all its elements are 0:

   ```
    char name[50] = { '\0' };
   ```

   But you can't put an initialiser inside the definition of a `struct`. The `struct` declaration only defines the general form of a composite object; it doesn't declare any instances of that object so there is nothing to initialise.

Comment: Thank you. This solved a lot of my doubts and was very easy to  digest. Thanks for taking your time to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Looks great. Remember that arrays start from 0. Change for loops to indexes 0 - 4.

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the id no., name and price of the product %d\n",i);
    scanf("%d%s%d",&p[i].id,&p[i].name,&p[i].price);
}
```

In general, I highly recommend using `fgets` for input of strings from user in order to avoid the risks of `scanf` + adds the NULL at end.

```
#include <string.h>

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the id no., name and price of the product %d\n",i);
    scanf("%d",&p[i].id);
    fgets(p[i].name, 50, stdin);
    scanf("%d",&p[i].price);
}
```

More about `fgets` -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgets-gets-c-language/

Comment: Your `fgets` proposal won't work unless the price is on a separate line from the name (which must be on the *same* line as the id or a blank name and a failed price-parse will ensue). And `&p[i].name` is the wrong type; that should be `p[i].name`. Regardless, the first part concerning zero-based indexing, is correct.

Comment: corret, Thank you very much!